# Camera's exposure was auto changed when I set custom mode - ios, objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

I'm using AVCaptureDevice to capture video frame to do some image process and would like to control the exposure duration, ISO by using

```
setExposureModeCustomWithDuration:(CMTime)duration ISO:(float)ISO completionHandler:(void (^)(CMTime syncTime))handler
```

And I think it will be keep the exposure level as my setting.

When I set the mode to AVCaptureExposureModeCustom, I can see preview image's brightness was changed when I move camera to capture different position. (Especially from light to dark side)

But when I change the exposure mode to AVCaptureExposureModeLocked, the brightness will be fixed.

I have been check the white-balance, focus, torchmode are locked or disable, isAdjustingExposure is keeping false,
and exposure duration and ISO parameter are not change during this problem happening.

```
- (void) setCameraExposure:(CMTime)exposureDuration ISO:(int)iso
{
    [self.avSession beginConfiguration];

    AVCaptureDevice *videoDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    if (videoDevice) {

        [videoDevice lockForConfiguration:nil];

        // Set exposure duration and ISO in custom mode
        if ([videoDevice isExposureModeSupported:AVCaptureExposureModeCustom]) {

            [videoDevice setExposureModeCustomWithDuration:exposureDuration
                                                       ISO:iso
                                         completionHandler:nil];
        }

        // If I use AVCaptureExposureModeLocked, the brightness was fixed
        //if ([videoDevice isExposureModeSupported:AVCaptureExposureModeLocked]) {
        //    [videoDevice setExposureMode:AVCaptureExposureModeLocked];
        //}

        // Lock white balance
        if ([videoDevice isWhiteBalanceModeSupported:AVCaptureWhiteBalanceModeLocked]) {
            [videoDevice setWhiteBalanceMode:AVCaptureWhiteBalanceModeLocked];
        }

        [videoDevice unlockForConfiguration];
    }

    [self.avSession commitConfiguration];
}
```

I want camera don't change brightness when I using **AVCaptureExposureModeCustom**, is it possible?
I've tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding a lock in the completion handler. Since you are sure, you don't observe any change when u lock it. Ideally it shouldn't change in custom mode also but I have also observed similar things in iOS camera